# Add element to elasticsearch array in node.js

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

Can someone help me add an element to my ElasticSearch array:

```
    let color = "red"

    client.update({
        index,
        type: "Cars",
        id,
        body: {
            script: {
                inline: "if(! ctx._source.colors.contains(color)){ ctx._source.colors += color }",
                params: {
                    color
                }
            }
        }
    })
```

For some reason, I keep getting `color` is not defined..

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to reference the param with: `params.color` in your script:

```
inline: "if(! ctx._source.colors.contains(params.color)){ ctx._source.colors += params.color }"
```